# ASP.NET - How to display javascript alert using C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page that contains a textbox and button, when the user clicks the submit button I want to display a message based on a bool value.

I have researched on stackoverflow and tried the code in this questions: [Asp.net Webform Display Alert and redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782354/asp-net-webform-display-alert-and-redirect)

But it didn't work. I have the following code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"", "alert('message')", true);
```

What code do I need to display the alert message?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what didn't work in the code from the question you referenced?

Comment: isn't that second parameter supposed to be the name of the updatepanel?  maybe I'm thinking of another register script method...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this simple method:

```
    private void MessageBox(string msg)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "<script language='javascript'>" + Environment.NewLine + "window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>";
    Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Comment: you are adding a script from code behind, I can't see any risk!

Comment: `Literal lit = new Literal();` is better I think, don't have to wrap a  `<span></span>` in this case.

Comment: yes I agree with Bruce, Literal is a better choice, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this apporch

```
 Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('The following errors have occurred: \n" + strErrorDesc + " .');</script>");
```

Comment: I get: `MyPage.aspx: ASP.NET Runtime Error: Only Content controls are allowed in a page that contains Content controls.`